# Подцепить файл модели к конроллеру автоматически

Tags: php

В данный момент подцепляю так:

```
$model_name = 'Model_'.$controller_name;
    $controller_name = 'Controller_'.$controller_name;
    $action_name = 'action_'.$action_name;

    // подцепляем файл с классом модели

    $model_file = strtolower($model_name).'.php';
    $model_path = "application/models/".$model_file;
    if(file_exists($model_path))
    {
        include "application/models/".$model_file;
    }
```

Исходя из данной конструкции я могу подцепить к контроллеру только модель с таким же названием, но возникла необходимость использовать еще одну модель (с другим названием), так вот, как это сделать?
В общем объясню подробнее что я хочу сделать: использую паттерн mvc, к шаблону страниц я создал контроллер и для него создал модель которая выводит список категорий, эти категории должны быть доступны на любой странице, поэтому добавил в шаблон:

```
class Controller_Template extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->model = Model_Template::get_data();
        $this->view = new View();
    }
    function action_index()

    {

            $data= Model_Template::get_data();
            $this->view->generate('main_view.php', 'template_view.php', $data);



        return true;


    }
```

Так вот теперь мне нужно использовать эту модель (Model_Template) для получения данных на других страницах, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: приведите код создания контроллера, пожалуйста.

Comment: Могу написать пример где задаем имя модели которые необходимы дополнительно в контроллере. Либо в основной моделе. Это будет с неограниченным количеством. Если такой вариант вас устроит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому интересно, то сделал иначе: переменную `$data` занес в сессию в контроллере Main: `$data = $_SESSION['gettypes'];` и на view шаблона подключил. Вариант не идеальный, но проблему решил.

Answer (score 1):

В PHP есть уже готовый функционал для этого. Называется автоматическая загрузка классов. Подробная информация и примеры есть в документации: [аutoload](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Простейший вариант использования. Определяете фунцию **__autoload**

```
 function __autoload($class_name) {
  ...
 }
```

В дальнейшем при попытке создать объект класса будет вызываться эта функция с именем класса как аргумент.

А дальше уже в зависимости от своих задач определяете какой файл нужно подключать.

И хотя не одобряю использование статических методов, но и для них эта функция работает. Только нужно принудительно вызвать лоадер. Например,  использовав вначале функцию **class_exists**

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вам стоит использовать паттерн Фабрика? Вот пример применения на основе Вашего кода:

```
<?php

class ModelFactory {

    /**
     * Метод для загрузки модели
     * @param type $model_file
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static function build($model_file) {
        try {
            $model_path = "application/models/" . $model_file;
            if (file_exists($model_path)) {
                include "application/models/" . $model_file;
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Файл модели отсутствует");
            }

            /**
             * После подключения файла с моделью, Вы можете сразу создать объект загружаемой модели и сразу его вернуть.
             * Например :
             * $model = new $model_file; или можете передать в этот метод еще одну переменную с названием класса модели и создавать объект используя другую переменную
             * return $model
             */
            return true;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }

    }
}
```

С помощью этого кода вы можете загружать любые файлы из папки `application/models/`. А если Вы хотите изменить папку, то можно, например, добавить в метод `build` еще одну переменную, в которой передавать путь к папке, где нужно искать модель.

Comment: использую mvc, с фабрикой не знаком

Comment: try-catch-throw?

Comment: @Etki да, именно так, поскольку я точно не знаю где будут обрабатываться исключения. Если не сразу в фабрике, а где-то уровнем выше, тогда проталкиваем исключение выше.

Comment: @Денис тогда советую Вам ознакомиться с книжкой  Мэтт Зандстра PHP: объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования. )